# Executable Jar not finding classes

Tags: java, class, reflection, jar, executable

My problem is that I have created an executable jar file that will scan classes in a Java project using the `Class.forName(...)` to get the class object, and then perform some operations. Now I want to use this executable jar in another project, but I'm running into a problem with the `Class.forName(...)` method not picking up the fully qualified name and getting a class not found exception. Now after some fiddling around with it I found that if I use a fully-qualified class name from the jar it works fine. So my issue is that it is using its own classpath, and not the classpath of the project that it is being used in. Is there a way to update the executable jar's classpath to include the classpath of the Java project that it is being used in?

Comment: How are you executing the jar file? Have you added the other jars to the `CLASSPATH`?

Comment: I want to execute the jar using ant (fails at the moment). A note is that when i create a class in the new project and instantiate the object for the entry point for the executable jar and call it, it works perfectly. So that issue is that when its run through ant some variables aren't being set properly.

Comment: Try running the ant task with `ant -v`, it should give you a great deal of detail.